# eclipse tomcat debug remote application

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, remote-debugging

I work with tomcat 9 and Eclipse oxygen.

I want to debug a remote application from

http://localhost:8080/regislab/

I followed the steps:

1.- In the directory Tomcat bin directory I created a setenv.bat

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

2.- I started the server with catalina.bat jpda start

3.- I configured Eclipse

From Debug As -> Debug Configurations -> New

[image]

4.- I clicked the button debug

I have breakpoints but the Eclipse debug perspective doesn't work.

In the tomcat console I see

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
04-Nov-2019 09:09:06.362 INFORMACI├ôN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Nombre de la versi├│n del servidor:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.27
```

How can I configure Tomcat server and Eclipse to debug a remote application?

Comment: "I have breakpoints but the Eclipse debug perspective doesn't work." debug perspective switch happens when the execution hits the debug point. are u sure the debug point is hit?

Comment: Debug perspective doesn't open

Comment: Try setting the breakpoints after you've connected to the application in the debugger.

Comment: The eclipse project' name is Regislab and the url is http://localhost:8080/regislab.